# Unknown column ''value'' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with phpmyadmin, like this:

Unknown column ''value'' in 'field list'

and my code:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pln`(`ppno`,`persno`,`pernum`,`psgrup`,`lv`,`pos`,`nppsimkp`,`persub`,`busrea`,`pdthr`,`gk`,`marstakey`,`bkey`,`bakun`,`numtd`,`email`,`bdate`) VALUES (`'$ppno'`,`'$persno'`,`'$pernum'`,`'$psgrup'`,`'$lv'`,`'$pos'`,`'$nppsimkp'`,`'$persub'`,`'$busrea'`,`'$pdthr'`,`'$gk'`,`'$marstakey'`,`'$bkey'`,`'$bakun'`,`'$numtd'`,`'$email'`,`'$bdate'`)") or die(mysql_error());
```

why that happen, I use backticks (`) because my input there is like "o'neil" and "jum'at".
thanks before.

Comment: You should not use both `'` and `\`` like `\`'$someVar'\``. It doesn't make sense. Second thing is that you should escape values before you put them into the query. Then you don't have to worry about `'` signs in values.

Comment: We just don't do it like this any more.

Answer (score 2):

[**`addslashes()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) might be a solution. This function will add slashes to escape your value (strings) which is causing the error, so for example if your string in `$persno` have quotes in the name you just need to escape it with the function

```
VALUES ('$ppno','".addlashes($persno)."','$pernum',
```

I would rather suggest to stop using mysql_* deprecated function and move on to either [**`PDO`**](https://www.php.net/PDO) or [**`mysqli`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and use **prepared statements** which will handle situation like this one and also will protect you from [**`mysql injections`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly replace your query with this, you had an error with that query

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pln`(`ppno`,`persno`,`pernum`,`psgrup`,`lv`,`pos`,`nppsimkp`,`persub`,`busrea`,`pdthr`,`gk`,`marstakey`,`bkey`,`bakun`,`numtd`,`email`,`bdate`) VALUES ('".$ppno."','".$persno."','".$pernum."','".$psgrup."','".$lv."','".$pos."','".$nppsimkp."','".$persub."','".$busrea."','".$pdthr."','".$gk."','".$marstakey."','".$bkey."','".$bakun."','".$numtd."','".$email."','".$bdate."'")") or die(mysql_error());
```